# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ',' Error

Tags: sql-server

This statement works if goes with only 1 column in a table BUT if more, this statement gives error.  Any idea why?  Thanks

```
DECLARE @TargetDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SourceDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @InsetRecords NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @TargetDB = 'MySSISDb'
SET @SourceDB = 'MySSISDb'

SET @InsetRecords = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TargetDB + '.dbo.Item2(ProductNumber, ProductName) 
             SELECT(ProductNumber, ProductName) 
             FROM ' + @SourceDB + '.dbo.Item'
EXEC (@InsetRecords)
```

Comment: As a start I would remove the parentheses around your select columns `SELECT(ProductNumber, ProductName)` should be `SELECT ProductNumber, ProductName`

Comment: WOW, Thanks a lot bluefeet... You're the man!  Happy New Year.  I'll continue my coding and let you know if I bumped to any further problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @TargetDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SourceDB NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @InsetRecords NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TargetDB = N'MySSISDb'
SET @SourceDB = N'MySSISDb'

SET @InsetRecords = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDB) + N'.[dbo].[Item2]([ProductNumber], [ProductName]) ' +
             N'SELECT [ProductNumber], [ProductName] ' + 
             N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SourceDB) + N'.[dbo].[Item]'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @InsetRecords
```

Comment: I will try this one too.  Thanks @M.Ali, thanks a lot for some idea.

Comment: @Bogart not a problem and it always best to use QUOTENAME function around your parameter in dynamic sql when you are concatenating the passed parameters to your sql and it is a sql object name, can protect you against a possible `Sql injection attack`.

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly, I just tried it.  Thanks a lot.  Now, I have problem when I used DateEffectiveFrom variable to insert in the table.  If gives me and error -Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2. Must declare the scalar variable "@DateEffectiveFrom".  Any idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: without looking at the code cant say much post your code please maybe then I can advise something.